# Make one Bootstrap dropdown menu show on hover, not all

Tags: drop-down-menu, dropdown

Bootstrap gurus.  I'd like to know if anyone has any examples of making one Bootstrap menu dropdown show on hover?  I have a Bootstrap menu bar of dropdowns and I only want one to drop down and display while being hovered.  I don't want all dropdowns to inherit this hover dropdown toggle.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling at all?
Here's just one of many examples that came up.
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-the-bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-work-on-hover--cms-33840

Comment: Hi, Phaelax z.  Yes, I did.  All of the examples show how to do it for all menu options.  I just need it for one menu option, not all.